# Run an AngularJS method on page load

Tags: angularjs

I have a custom scope method within a Controller, and when a custom directive loads, I want to run a method inside the defined controller. I've seen a lot of options, but which one could be referenced inside a template via an ng-* call? Otherwise, what are the best options?

Comment: If you want something to happen when a directive is used, why don't you put that code in the directive? The directive shouldn't be aware of the controller controlling the template that uses the directive.

Comment: It sounds as if you want to run some code defined in your controller as soon as a directive is initialized. Could you please add some more details on the use case to your question for us to understand better what you want to achieve. Probably there is a better way of handling this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on angular 1.5 already and can use the new `component` way to build your custom directive, you could use the newly introduced `$onInit` method instead of polluting the constructor, that should only initalize the object itself.

For details, please see this blogpost: https://toddmotto.com/on-init-require-object-syntax-angular-component/

Answer (score 2):

Since the controller is instantiated when the directive is loaded, any method called in your controller will be called on page load. In my code it is often something like

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('controllerName', ctrl);

function ctrl() {

/*--------Initialize--------*/
someMethod()
}
```

Comment: How would I do this if I have a function declared inside my existing Controller? This is how its declared right now, for review. The $scope method is the method I want to run when this controller loads.

`app.controller(TestController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.load_records = function () {
//Code goes here
 });
    };
});`

Comment: just putting `$scope.load_records()` anywhere in your controller will cause that method to be called when the controller is loaded